# How to delete external images after breaking links to them using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following Word macro which breaks links to external pictures making them embedded in the document:

```
For Each objField In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If Not objField.LinkFormat Is Nothing Then
        objField.LinkFormat.Update
        objField.LinkFormat.BreakLink
        ActiveDocument.UndoClear
    End If
Next
```

It works great, but after breaking of links I no longer need external pictures that were used in the document. I may delete them using [this method](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/DeleteFiles.htm), but I'm afraid to delete images not associated with the document. How can I get a list of image filenames that were used in the document and then delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the LinkFormat.SourceFullName property inside the loop to insert each link in an array. Then, read this array in a loop to delete each element using the Killfile function.